# Effect on HTTP legacy protocol server key of adding or removing APNS Certificate to existing Firebase Cloud Messaging project

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, firebase-console

I have FCM push notifications implemented on a server.
I want to additionally send APNS notifications via that server by sending as a FCM message that is forwarded by Firebase to APNS.
To do that I understand I need to add APNS certificate to the firebase console.

FCM push notifications on my server were implemented some time back when FCM HTTP legacy protocol was available and server API keys were visible in the Firebase console (I got the key from somewhere so I guess it was there).

My question is if I add (and perhaps later remove) an APNS certificate to my firebase console production project will that affect the validity of my existing server API key in any way. It is important that FCM continues to work seamlessly.

It doesn't seem possible to get a FCM HTTP legacy protocol server key now. If there is a way to do this then I could try this myself on a test project.